# Libre office and in line editing

Tags: libreoffice

I can't know for certain if this problem has been raised and solved before in this forum, as I don't quite know what the proper term is to describe it.

When I go back to previous paragraphs in libre writer and try to add in words, those added words, as they're typed, erase the letters in front of them in that paragraph, as if taking up that words space.  I remember turning this feature off in microsoft word, but I cannot remember what it is called nor how to do it.

Would be great if someone could help me out.

Comment: have you tried pressing the insert key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I did not understood this question, but maybe (again) your problem is with the Insert Key, did you remember of having pushed it, and when its pushed the cursor looks like a big black block on the text editor.